# Error 500 when I called webservice with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

I have web service solution in Visual Studio with one parameter :

```
Public Function CheckPalletInLocation(location As String) As String

       Dim ScaleConnnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("MYCONNEXION")
       Dim ScaleCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
       ScaleCommand.Connection = ScaleConnnection
       ScaleConnnection.Open()
       ScaleCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT LOGISTICS_UNIT FROM LOCATION_INVENTORY WHERE LOCATION = '" &
       location & "'"
       Return ScaleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
       ScaleConnnection.Close()

       'Return "True"
   End Function
```

When I launch solution, webservice works. It return value.
Now I want to call it in HTML page with ajax code :

```
<pre><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
        <title>TEST WEB SERVICE</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</HEAD>

    <BODY onload="Click_BB();">PAGE
    <script>

    function Click_BB()
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'https://localhost:44341/WebService1.asmx?op=CheckPalletInLocation',
          contentType: "application/xml",
          data: { location: '110-01-03-10' },
          success: function (d) 
              {
                alert(d);
              },
          failure: function (response) 
              {
                debugger;
                alert(response.d);
              }
        });
    }
    
    </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I always have this error in the response page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="fr">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Le serveur n'a pas pu traiter la demande. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Données non valides au niveau racine. Ligne 1, position 1.
```

I transale : server cannot process. Invalid data root, line 1 position 1

Can someone help please ?

Thanks

I tried to change AJAX code, I would like to have the result of my web service in HTML page. Until now I have error 500

Comment: The data you're submitting is not in a valid XML-format (SOAP envelope), so the parser can't parse the data you provide (probably JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You want to send XML (a SOAP envelope) to the server with the correct location data:

Add a variable containing a valid `soap-envelope` as a string to be used by your webservice. Add these properties to the `Click_BB` function:

`dataType: "xml",`
`data: soapMessage,`

You probably want to setup the `soap:Body` like this:

```
<soap:Body>
    <CheckPalletInLocation>
         <location>110-01-03-10</location> 
    </CheckPalletInLocation>
</soap:Body>`
```

---

Change the function:

```
function Click_BB()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'https://localhost:44341/WebService1.asmx?op=CheckPalletInLocation',
      contentType: "application/xml",
      dataType: "xml", 
      data: soapMessage, 
      success: function (d) 
          {
            alert(d);
          },
      failure: function (response) 
          {
            debugger;
            alert(response.d);
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did but now I have this error "'soap' is not declared prefix. Line 1, position 2"

Answer (score 0):

it works I put this code :

```
var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<soap:Body> ' +
                    '<CheckPalletInLocation  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> ' +
                         '<location>110-01-03-10</location> ' +
                    '</CheckPalletInLocation> ' +
                    '</soap:Body>`' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
```